# FIWARE how to access KeyRock IdM token from Wirecloud widget

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

In the global Wirecloud instance i have a widget which uses the KeystoneAPI mentioned here:
https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/object_storage_api/

So far so good.

However now i want to move to KeyRock for authentication. I still want to  pass tokens from my wirecloud widget to backend services like the Wilma PEP proxy which is not connected to KeyRock as well. But the KeystoneAPI seems to be tied to Keystone (hence the name probably).

Is there a KeyRockAPI accessible from Wirecloud widgets? How can a widget obtain the KeyRock OAuth2 token the user logged in with? I cannot find any documentation on this.

Comment: typo, the Wilma PEP Proxy is **now** connected to KeyRock as well

Comment: Installed docker containers of KeyRock and Wirecloud, tried out the objectstorage demo widget, which failed to retrieve an authentication token. Traced the problem to %idm_token% not being filled in by the python code, presumably in plugins.py because it looks for an AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND of 'fiware' whereas the documentation states to include 'wirecloud.fiware.social_auth_backend.FIWAREOAuth2'. Any help is welcome with this, we are really stuck. Should we debug the plugins.py code? If so, how (we are not Django/Python developers).

Comment: Strangely, the objectstorage works on the fiware labs wirecloud instance (after adding a doc/index.html file to the widget ??). So something is configured differently there.

Comment: some digging brought me here: https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/blob/0.9.x-develop/docs/slides/3.1.8_Accessing_third-party_servicies_using_IdM_tokens.md  which i followed, but am getting an unclear response from my widget's javascript console

"{"description": "Current user has not an active FIWARE profile"}"
responseText
:
"{"description": "Current user has not an active FIWARE profile"}"
responseXML
:
null
status
:
422
statusText
:
"UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY". }   I followed the "UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY" message back to plugins.py again.  This must be a configuration issue somewhere??

Comment: And yes, the widget is being used by a user that is logged into Wirecloud using an account in the KeyRock IdM, both running on separate docker containers.

Comment: I ran my test widget on the fiware labs instance mashup and it worked, but with interesting results. The organisations field was empty but it returned a field "app_id": "17". Presumably wirecloud is application 17 in the IdM, but hidden from end-users. So my authentication token from wirecloud will be bound to that application? If so, the token is useless to my own application unless i can get a new token for it. Am i wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WireCloud doesn't allow widgets and operators to read the OAuth2 token assigned to the user, but it provide support for injecting the token into HTTP requests if they go through the WireCloud's proxy. This injection is controlled by several HTTP headers, this is an example:

```js
MashupPlatform.http.makeRequest(url, {
    requestHeaders: {
        "X-FI-WARE-OAuth-Token": "true",
        "X-FI-WARE-OAuth-Header-Name": "X-Auth-Token"
    },
    ...
});
```

You can find more info about how to use this feature in the [FIWARE Academy course](https://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=53#section-3), more specifically in the `3.1.8. Accessing third-party services using IdM tokens` section (take into account that this document is the same you pointed in your comments, but in html format ;) ).

#### Answers to the others questions formulated as comments:

- > Installed docker containers of KeyRock and Wirecloud, tried out the objectstorage demo widget, which failed to retrieve an authentication token. Traced the problem to %idm_token% not being filled in by the python code, presumably in plugins.py because it looks for an AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND of 'fiware' whereas the documentation states to include 'wirecloud.fiware.social_auth_backend.FIWAREOAuth2'.

  I recommend you to create a new question in StackOverflow to tackle this problem. Please, provide more details on your configuration.
- > So my authentication token from wirecloud will be bound to that application? If so, the token is useless to my own application unless i can get a new token for it. Am i wrong here?

  Yeah, the Mashup portal is the application number 17 in the Account portal and the OAuth2 token obtained by WireCloud is bound to that application. I cannot foresee if that token is useful for your application or not. This token can be used for authenticating users, but the IdM limits the returned information (e.g. roles) depending on the application bounded to the token. So, evidently, this integration is not perfect, but we are missing some integration features from the IdM to make it more useful.